# Unable to connect SQL Server from a PC while it is accessed from other PC

Tags: sql-server

I try to search my problem and found lots of threads, but all of them server related. All suggestion/tips regrading Database server related.
I have a database server (SQL Server 2014) hosted on VPS. Server is running fine without any issue, and working fine from all computer over internet. But from one PC it is not connecting. I disabled antivirus, added program on exception list on firewall,but still I am unable to connect the server, while that server are access from other PC. This PC connecting on internet through cable internet connection and operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate (I called service provider, and confirmed that they are not blocking/filtering any IP).
Thanks in advance.
Error Details:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Have you opened port 1433 on client machine? (Assuming default sql server port).

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: Mr. D K thanks for your response. No, I did not open the port, just allow the program on firewall on client machine. I also read that link, if I am not wrong, that is for server related tips, but there is no issue on server, because I can work from other PC, which is connected through broadband/data card.

Comment: On the client which doesn't connect check network protocol used. Named Pipes looks strange for external connection. Should be TCP/IP.